# how make xmlschema only look locally provided schemas

Tags: python, python-3.x, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to force `xmlschema` library to validate only against locally provided schemas (and not any schema provided in XML)

XML can provide different versions of schema as absolute url but I want map those urls to local directory so I doesn't need network access.

For example if schema in XML is `https://example.com/v1.0.0/schema.xsd`,
I want to look in `/path/to/some/dir/v1.0.0/schema.xsd`

How this can be done in `xmlschema`?

I tried to load XML using `xml.etree.ElementTree` and find the schema URL and create a `XMLShema` object to validate against, Is there a better way to do this?